# How does IE10 run in both Metro Mode and Desktop Mode in Windows 8?

Tags: directx, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I read that Metro Apps do not run in Desktop mode (on Intel) and Desktop Apps do not run on Metro. Yet there is IE10 running in both places. How is this done?

Are the tools available for anyone to write windows native Apps like this that work in both modes?

Comment: There are two IE10s: that's the short answer.

Comment: @KateGregory No, there is only one, `iexplore.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Developing a Metro style enabled Desktop Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465413.aspx).

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks. Just what I was looking for, and didn't find so far. The architecture is just breathtaking. Thanks again.

Comment: I still do not understand what exactly gives the rights to a native application to run in metro mode. Is it setting the program as default browser in windows by "Set User Defaults" (SUD) and "Set Program Access and User Defaults (SPAD)" tells Windows that the program is allowed to run in Metro with Win32 access? Anybody?

Comment: You follow the instructions in the "Installation" section of the document.